# ess: transform a text selection into an R vector

Tags: ess

Is there any `ess` function that does the following? Assume you have the line in Emacs like this

```
1 2 3 4
```

then once selected (e.g., using the mouse), it is transformed into

```
c(1,2,3,4)
```

It would be a wonderful tool. I copy and paste stuff that I transform into vectors quite often. Also, it would be great to have a function that if you select

```
A B C D E
```

it produces

```
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a solution based on `ess`, but both of these are relatively simple to implement using Elisp.

For your first example, that is, `1 2 3 4` => `c(1,2,3,4)`: use the Elisp functions `format` and `replace-regexp-in-string` to convert your data as text using a regular expression.

Put this Elisp command somewhere in your `init.el`:

```
(defun my-command (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (insert
    (prog1
      (format "c(%s)"
        (replace-regexp-in-string 
          "\\([[:digit:]]+\\) " 
          "\\1," 
          (buffer-substring-no-properties start end)))
      (delete-region start end))))
```

Mark a space-separated sequence of numbers, then invoke it with <kbd>M-x my-command RET</kbd>, or bind `my-command` to the key combination of your choice for easy access.